# Subversion option to display results of update without actually updating

Tags: svn, perforce, synchronization

The perforce command:

`p4 sync -n`

will display the results of the sync (update in subversion) without actually performing the sync.

I've been looking in the svn help pages and googling around for a tag/command in subversion that will do the same but have yet to find one.  I was thinking there may be a tag for svn update that would accomplish this.  Is there one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To see what an update will change, enter:

```
svn status -u
```

This is like `svn status` but also displays files which would be updated.

You can then see individual differences by running `svn status`/`svn diff` on individual files.

Comment: svn status -u is what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Are you just looking to see changes?  I'd look at the `diff` command.  Example [here](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2008-01/0313.shtml).